# Blocking a table whilst it is being reloaded

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In our data warehouse, we have a table which gets truncated/reloaded every hour. This process normally takes a few seconds.

We found lately that some reports that hook off them came out blank, and found that the task that loads this table took 10 minutes instead of a few seconds (separate issue which I've fixed).

What we want to do is lock this table whilst the truncate/reload is happening. How can we do this so that any query that is looking at this table will be blocked until the task is complete? Do we simply wrap a transaction around it?

EDIT: I've tested this and it seems to do what I want. Is this the right way to go about things?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
  TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MatProduct
  INSERT INTO dbo.MatProduct (
  ...
  )
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  --Rethrow the error
  DECLARE 
    @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ErrorSeverity INT,
    @ErrorState INT
  SELECT 
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
  RAISERROR (
    @ErrorMessage,
    @ErrorSeverity,
    @ErrorState    
  )

  --Rollback the transaction if an error occurred
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH

--Commit the transaction if there were no errors
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: The use of `TRANSACTION` would ensure the atomicity of your transaction, ie, there will be either a complete set of your insert or no insert at all based on your example. However, the table is not locked, or there wouldn't be any blocked when the task is being executed.

Comment: @ydoow so how do I ensure that any query accessing this table is not going to get a blank table? I thought that using a transaction, unless the issuing sessions are using something like `read uncomitted`, that they would get the results before the transactions starts (ie a table with data), or after the transaction has been committed.. but nothing in between?

Comment: @ydoow- I think we are saying the same thing. However, you say the table is not locked or blocked. I tried in a separate session to access the data whilst the table had been truncated and got a blocked session until I comitted or rolled back the transaction which is what I wanted.

Comment: A proper set on isolation level would probably meet your requirement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173763.aspx